# issues adding JLabel returned from method to JPanel in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I am trying to make a gui for a flashcard application that can use both images and text as the "front" and "back" of the flashcard. The issue is my TextSide and ImageSide classes (which both implement a Side interface) have a method getContent() which is supposed to return a JLabel, but something is going awry when I try to add the returned JLabel to a JPanel.

Here is an excerpt from the main class which is where the issue is actually occurring. other classes follow in case the problem is actually there.

note: a window is appearing. the buttons appear just fine. the text entry box does, too. but the north displayCard JPanel is there but empty.

one other note: main class is calling study method which calls flashcard which calls textSide.

[image: here's what it looks like]

```
static void theGui(StudyMethod method){

  final StudyMethod meth = method;
  final boolean flip = false;
  final JPanel displayCard = new JPanel();
  displayCard.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  meth.pickCard();
  JLabel p = meth.getAnswer();
  System.out.println(p);
  displayCard.add(p);
  displayCard.revalidate();
  displayCard.repaint();


  final JTextArea textInput = new JTextArea(10, 20);

  JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
  buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  JButton dontKnow = new JButton("Do Not Know");
  JButton know = new JButton("I Know");
  JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
  JButton flipIt = new JButton("Flip");

  buttons.add(dontKnow);
  buttons.add(know);
  buttons.add(exit);
  buttons.add(flipIt);

  JPanel gui = new JPanel();
  gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  gui.add(displayCard, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  gui.add(textInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  gui.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.add(gui);

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

TextSide class:

```
package flashcards;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextSide implements Side{

private String text;
private JLabel label;

TextSide(String text){
    this.text = text;
    label = new JLabel(text);
}

public JLabel getContent(){
    return label;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}}
```

drill(study method) class

```
package flashcards;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Drill implements StudyMethod{

Box box;

public Drill(Box box){

        this.box = box;
}


  /**
   * Picks a random card from this.box
   * @precondition there must be at least one card.
   */
public void pickCard() {

    int maxCard = box.size();//maximum value of card
    int rndVal = rand.nextInt(maxCard);//random value not to exceed maxCard value
    card = box.get(rndVal);//chooses random card
    displayFront = (rand.nextInt(2) == 0);//decides whether to display front or back

}

/**
   * Returns the question for the last picked card.
   *
   * @return the question
   *
   * @precondtion pickCard() has been called at least once
   */
  public JLabel getQuestion()
  {
    assert card != null;

    return displayFront ? card.getChallenge() : card.getResponse();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the answer for the last picked card.
   *
   * @return the answer
   *
   * @precondtion pickCard() has been called at least once
   */
  public JLabel getAnswer()
  {
    assert card != null;

    return displayFront ? card.getResponse() : card.getChallenge();
  }

  public boolean checkAnswer(String s)
  {
    assert s != null;

    boolean isCorrect = "".equals(s) || (getOtherSide().getText().equals(s));

    if (isCorrect)
    {
        box.remove(card);
    }

    return isCorrect;
  }

  /**
   * @precondition this.box.size >= 1
   */
    public boolean hasCards() {

        if (box.size() > 0){return true;}
        else return false;

    }

    public Side getSide(){
          return displayFront ? card.back : card.front;
      }
    public Side getOtherSide(){
          return displayFront ? card.front : card.back;
      }

 private FlashCard card = null; // last picked card.
 private boolean displayFront = true; // indicates side to display.
 private final Random rand = new Random(); /// random number generator.
}
```

the flashcard class

```
package flashcards;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Represents a text based flashcard.
 *
 * This class is immutable.
 * @invariant front != null && back != null
 */
public class FlashCard
{
/**
* Constructor setting up a flashcard object.
*
* @param challenge front of the card
* @param response back of the card
* @precondition challenge != null && response != null
*/
FlashCard(String challenge, String response)
{
assert challenge != null && response != null;

if (challenge.contains(".") &&    
(challenge.substring(challenge.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".jpg")
    || (challenge.substring(challenge.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".jpeg"))
    || (challenge.substring(challenge.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".gif"))
    || (challenge.substring(challenge.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".png")))){

    front = new ImageSide(challenge);

}
else{front = new TextSide(challenge);}

if (response.contains(".") &&           
(response.substring(response.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".jpg")
        || (response.substring(response.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".jpeg"))
        || (response.substring(response.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".gif"))
        || (response.substring(response.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".png")))){

        back = new ImageSide(challenge);

    }
else {back = new TextSide(response);}
}

/** Returns the front side. */
public JLabel getChallenge() { return front.getContent(); }

/** Returns the back side. */
public JLabel getResponse() { return back.getContent(); }

public final Side front;
public final Side back;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, it's possible that the images aren't been loaded.  What does the `ImageSide` and `TextSide` classes look like

Comment: TextSide is posted in the original. ImageSide is relevant to the application, but my specific problem right now is just getting the JLabel from getContent() in TextSide which is called by Flashcard's getResponse() or getChallenge() method which is called by Drill's getAnswer() or getQuestion() method

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is too much unneeded code and it doesn't compile because of missing definitions so we can't really see the problem. I suggest you start from scratch and create a mini-copy of this program that demonstrates the problem (surely, adding a label to a panel doesn't require 4 classes and 2 interfaces).

Comment: I made an MVCE, and to my chagrin, it is working. So clearly there is something going on that I've overlooked.

Comment: Welcome to the world of debugging :) Start adding code to your MCVE until it breaks. Then if you can't figure out why it happens, post this MCVE here and we will help. Also, use @username to reply to comments.

Comment: @user1803551, thanks for the help! And yeah, debugging this one has been tricky as I can't just run the debugger in Eclipse like I'm accustomed to doing. So far everything is working right with FlashCards that have TextSides, and now to move onto making the images work!

Comment: *" I can't just run the debugger in Eclipse"* Why not? There is nothing out of the ordinary in this code.

Comment: @user1803551, I'm having IO problems. It doesn't want to let me import flashcards. (I'm super noob, so I'm probably just doing something wrong)

Comment: What do IO problems have to do with imports? Also, what is "doesn't want to let me"? What does it say?

Comment: Is this solved? If so, please post the solution in an answer.

Comment: yes, it's mostly solved. I'll post the solution in full shortly

Comment: sorry for delay! (busy student, ya know). Here's the full code on paste bin: http://pastebin.com/HAH0PBu8

Comment: Who the hell is upvoting all your stuff that looks very suspicious.

Comment: @Snickers3192 I think it was one of my fellow students that I tutored; I guess he thought it works like reddit. Feel free to compensate with a barrage of down votes.